# Veeam Backup Size Calculation

Tags: backup, veeam

This is just an informative question about Veeam Backup size. I was setting some backup tasks in Veeam Backup and FastSCP v4.1.1. And while setting I checked the entire backup size of that task and I could see as shown below:

[image]

Source data is shown as 136 GB. But I am confused with the other two sections. What does these mean?
How estimated required space is calculated.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veeam can compress and dedupe your data, so it makes a best guess on how big your compressed and deduped backup set is going to be. That's the "Estimated full backup size".

As for the Estimated Required Space, what version of Veeam is this? I believe there was a bug circa 2010 that miscalculated disk sizes based thin provisioned disks.

Comment: Thanks..My veeam version is 4.1.1, I have already specified this in the question.

Comment: @serverstackqns sorry, I thought you were on some version of FastSCP v4.1.1 - I forgot that it was on the same as Veeam. Veeam Backup and Recovery has gotten much, much better in recent years, so if you can afford an upgrade I highly recommend it.